# callback issue? Want to execute code in child popup (modal) window (colorbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

We're using colorboxes (popup modals) on our site - and i'm wanting to remove a button when the popup happens.

This is in the code (but I can't edit this part):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".quickview_btn").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var qvURL = $(this).attr("href");
            $.colorbox({"href": qvURL})
        });
        $.colorbox.resize();
    });
</script>
```

And I'm injecting code trying to overwrite/alter it like below:

```
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function(){

    var qvURL = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".quickview_btn").colorbox({ 

        width: "50%", 
        height: "50%", 
        iframe: true, 
        href: qvURL, 
        opacity: 0.6,
        onComplete: function(){
          $('.add-to-cart').hide();
        }

});
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: You have a document ready within another document ready there - not the issue, but not necessary

Comment: You have two percentage signs in height.

Comment: Have you opened up the console and seen what errors are popping up? @BramVanroy has made a good point.

Comment: var qvURL = $(this).attr("href"); won't work in your code, as `this` refers to document. You have to refer to your button there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the advice people.

I've finally got it working and i took some of your tips.

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".quickview_btn" ).click(function() {
        var quickview_url = $(this).attr("href");


    var qvURL = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".quickview_btn").colorbox({ 
        href: qvURL, 
        opacity: 0.6,
        onComplete: function(){
        $( ".qlBtns" ).click(function() {

                mboxDefine('dynamicElement5', 'QuickViewAddToCartClicked');
                mboxUpdate( 'QuickViewAddToCartClicked', 'Clicked=Yess');

        });
    }
});


        mboxDefine('dynamicElement', 'QuickViewPLPclicked');
        mboxUpdate( 'QuickViewPLPclicked', 'paramURL='+quickview_url);
    });

});
</script>
```